# Missing assets on production mode - passenger on nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production-environment

When i move to production many assets are missing. There is no background image but there are styles for background from css. Many JS doesn't load ..

I put in config production.rb :

```
  config.cache_classes = true


  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true
```

In application.rb :

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( ie.css )
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

but fonts doesnt load. I see in public/assets all fonts but there isnt any on my site.

Can someone write answer - how config application to work on production ? Why i have xxx.jpg from css file but havent got yyy.jpg from that same css file..

CSS for background:

```
body{
line-height: 1;
background: #fff url('wallpaper.jpg') top left;
```

IMAGES location - assets/images

FONTS location - assets/fonts

Sometimes in chrome console i see :

```
GET ..../assets/wallpaper.jpg 404 (Not Found) xxxxxx/:11
GET...../assets/main_page.png 404 (Not Found) xxxxxx/:30
GET ...../assets/fonts/Lato-Bol.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

and sometimes not, but always there is no fonts and many assets.

My application css:

```
*= require_self
*= require chosen
*= require fancybox
*= require page
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Comment: please post your css code, images locations and log.

Comment: and ? is there some way to put app on production mode? why there is no any one full tutorial or i dont know, book about what should be changed when move to production server.

Comment: config.assets.compile = true - when i do this assets work - but this cant be set to true on production mode

Comment: ok soo the problem is with images in css - when i copy images to public/assets from app/assets/images - there are on site. What i do wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `image-url` instead of `url`.

```
background: #fff image-url('wallpaper.jpg') top left;
```

From the [Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and
>   sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass,
>   underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font,
>   video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

Comment: its not an answer. Even if it will work there is still problem with fonts - they also doesnt show without config.assets.compile = true

Comment: site.com/assets/fancybox-y-ed93c57f5560842265c471035f095ec7.png - page doesnt exist.

Comment: OK image-url works for images - what i can do with fonts now?

Comment: NO it still doesnt work, only one image is loaded right now, other even when i use image-url does not show on site

Comment: where are you placing fonts? be sure to set config.action_controller.asset_host and add the assets to config.assets.precompile if they are not being required anywhere. you may need to read all the Asset Pipeline documentation before going on.